# How does an iterator works internally in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

I am unable to understand how iterator works exactly in C++. As I read in some blogs that iterator does not contain address. If it does not contain address then how exactly are we incrementing it like `it++` or `++it`.

Lets take an example of a vector iterator.

```
vector<int> ::iterator it;
for(it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); it++)
{
    // do something
}
```

if iterator is not a pointer containing an address then what exactly is it++ doing. What is it storing. How is it working internally. How is iterator exactly pointing to the elements of a vector?

Comment: You don't seem to have a code problem but rather some generic question about C++.

Comment: Are you aware of what *operator overloading* is?

Comment: "*if iterator is not a pointer containing an address*", Technically, a pointer would be very valid iterator for `std::vector` (and is probably used in most C++ standard library implementations), but it could also be a class designed for that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I don't think any of the major standard library implementations use pointers for `std::vector` iterators (https://godbolt.org/z/t5NhEp).

Comment: @walnut  ok so if it is operator overloading then what exactly is it storing?

Comment: @pujadeo The class with the overloaded operators can store whatever it needs to identify the element in the container, but most likely it will store just a pointer to the element as member in the case of `std::vector`.

Comment: then why not directly store the base address and get done with it?

Comment: @pujadeo As mentioned above, a simple pointer would be valid for a `std::vector` iterator as well, but I assume that most implementations add optional out-of-bounds checks etc. to the iterator class. For other containers such as `std::list`, a pointer will not be sufficient, because the elements are not stored consecutively and so a class with operators overloaded to e.g. find the correct next element are necessary. The iterator concept is a generalization of the pointer concept.

Comment: `The iterator concept is a generalization of the pointer concept.` so nicely explained, thank you so much @walnut

Comment: but wait iterators are internally pointing to an address only right? so is there any way to print address using iterators?

Comment: You cannot print iterators like you can with pointers, but you can always obtain the address of an element in the container from an iterator `it` using `&*it` (for full generality `std::addressof(*it)`). The pointer is useless though if the container is not a continuous container, because you cannot increment or decrement it to get to the next element.

Comment: @pujadeo Not only, they can be, especially in the case of `std::vector`.

Comment: @walnut Just tell me if I am right. So iterator is like an object. When we use `*it` it is not exactly dereferencing but just operator overloading to show the same concept as it. `it++` in similar way is overloaded and there is no exact increment of any address.

Comment: Sorry if too many questions here. I am just a noob. Who knows if I can get my doubts clear today. I can be as good as you guyz in future

Comment: @pujadeo Yes, although the word "*dereference*" and "*increment*" are still used when referring to iterators. Talking about "*pointers*" and "*addresses*" does however in general not apply to iterators. See also the answer posted just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we cannot assume that an iterator is a pointer, this does not imply that
the iterator cannot rely internally on a pointer.
An iterator can be thought about as a *metaphor* of a pointer (that we can
increment, dereference...) and then in some cases (array, vector) this iterator
can be simply made of a pointer to the elements (not necessarily be exactly
this pointer, but rather a structure with such a pointer as data member).

The main advantage is that all the details are hidden inside this *metaphor*
and in trivial cases (like the vector in the following example) it behaves
exactly as if we had actually used a pointer, but in other cases (like the list
in the following example) it does something probably very different.
We don't have to bother about that, we just write the code in the same way,
and we can even write generic code that behaves accordingly.

Note that the explicit usage of iterators in the following example are
let here to match your initial question; it would better to rely on
range-for loops in real code.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
void
display(const char *title,
        const T &container)
{
  using std::cbegin;
  using std::cend;
  std::cout << title;
  for(auto it=cbegin(container); it!=cend(container); ++it) // range-for would be better
  {
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
  const auto v=std::vector<int>{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
  const auto l=std::list<int>{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
  //
  std::cout << "specific v:";
  for(auto it=cbegin(v); it!=cend(v); ++it) // range-for would be better
  {
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  //
  std::cout << "specific l:";
  for(auto it=cbegin(l); it!=cend(l); ++it) // range-for would be better
  {
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  //
  display("generic v:", v);
  display("generic l:", l);
  return 0;
}
```